# Google Cloud Platform to AWS migration [PostgreSQL 9.6]

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, postgresql-9.6, django-2.1

I'm working on a Django (2.1) project that is hosted on Google Cloud Platform with a ~= 7GB size PostgreSQL (9.6) database.

The documentation doesn't cover this specific version of PostgreSQL, so I'm stuck in the DMS endpoints configurations to connect the old database and perform the instance replication with DMS (Database Migration Service) from AWS.

I've followed this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-amazon-dms-to-perform-a-database-migrat), but there is no details about the endpoints configuration. Nothing on the documentations too (I've spent a lot of time searching on it). Only with a feel other specific databases like Oracle and MySQL.

I need to know how to configure the Source and Target endpoints of the instance on AWS DMS, so I can connect my database on GCP and start the replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my answer by trial and error.

Actually the configuration is pretty straightfoward, after I found out that I did not create the RDS instance first:

1. RDS - First you need to create your DB instance that will host your DB. After creating you can see the endpoint and port of your database: e.g. Endpoint `your-database.xxxxxxxxxxxx.sa-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` port `5432`;
2. DMS - On Database Migration Service painel, go to Replication Instance and create a new one. Set the VPC to the one that you've created or the default one if it works for you.
3. Source Endpoint - Configure with the Google Cloud PLatform IP setted on your Django project `settings.py`. The source endpoint work getting your DB from GCP using the IP;
4. Target Endpoint - Set this one with the address and port that you created at step 1;
5. Test connection.

After many trials I've completed my database migration successfully.

Hope this help someone who's passing trough the same problems.